# A program compiled statically with MPICH will have issues with runtimes of a different version?

Tags: mpi, mpich

I haven't read very much about MPI's implementation yet, but I was asked to setup a third party software statically linked against version 1.4.1pl of MPICH2 with an environment that runs the MPICH2 runtime with version 1.2.1.

Should I expect problems?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I have had issues before compiling a library with one MPI installation and then running it using `mpirun` from another installation. Do you _have_ to use different versions?

Comment: I don't know for sure if this would break, but it's certainly possible, depending on how much the mpiexec+mpd has varies between these versions, and it would be the first thing I'd look at if there were problems.  If the third party software comes with the complete mpi installation - eg, version-appropriate mpiexec and mpd - then you should be fine, but you'll want to make sure the other version is nowhere in your executable or library paths.   If it doesn't, I'd suggest also installing the 1.2.1 version of the MPICH2 setup and using that when running this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably work, but it's not ideal.  There are certainly bugs in 1.2.1 that have long been fixed.  And since we don't usually test mixed version installations, bugs are more likely to occur in mixed version installations.

If you have odd configurations of the 1.2.1 environment (non-default process managers or PMI libraries), then the odds of a problem increase substantially.